# How to extract paths to 'enabled' objects in nested object arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion

I'm a novice to recursion and I have a JSON structure with arrays of nested objects. Some of these objects have a boolean enabled: true. I'm trying to figure out how to extract the paths to all enabled objects and their children.

I tried both cleaning up the original object by removing unused paths but I got lost in accessing the parents. I also tried building a separate array of paths using dot-notation, as I can probably build a new nested object from that. My latest attempt at the dot-notation extract:

```
    const sourceData = {
      title: "Work",
      tags: [
        {
          title: "Cleaning",
          tags: [
            {
              title: "Floors"
            },
            { title: "Windows", enabled: true },
            { title: "Ceilings", enabled: true }
          ]
        },
        {
          title: "Maintenance",
          tags: [
            {
              title: "Walls",
              enabled: true,
              tags: [
                {
                  title: "Brickwall"
                },
                {
                  title: "Wooden wall"
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              title: "Roof"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          title: "Gardening"
        }
      ]
    };

    function getEnabledPaths(level, acc) {
      for (const tag of level.tags) {
        if (tag.enabled) {
          return tag.title;
        } else if (tag.hasOwnProperty("tags")) {
          var path = this.getEnabledPaths(tag);
          if (path) acc.push(tag.title + "." + path);
        }
      }
      return acc;
    }

    console.log(getEnabledPaths(sourceData, []));
```

I only get:

```
    [
      "Cleaning.Windows",
      "Maintenance.Walls"
    ]
```

I would ideally end up with something like this:

```
    [
      'Work.Cleaning.Windows',
      'Work.Cleaning.Ceilings',
      'Work.Maintenance.Walls.Brickwall',
      'Work.Maintenance.Walls.Wooden Wall'
    ]
```

In a perfect world (but I tried for days and went back to getting the dot notation results):

```
    {
      title: "Work",
      tags: [
        {
          title: "Cleaning",
          tags: [
            {
              title: "Windows",
              enabled: true
            },
            {
              title: "Ceilings",
              enabled: true
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          title: "Maintenance",
          tags: [
            {
              title: "Walls",
              enabled: true,
              tags: [
                {
                  title: "Brickwall"
                },
                {
                  title: "Wooden wall"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key to the recursion function is to both a) deal with children and b) the item itself.

Here's my take, which seems to work:

```js
const sourceData = {title:"Work",tags:[{title:"Cleaning",tags:[{title:"Floors"},{title:"Windows",enabled:true},{title:"Ceilings",enabled:true}]},{title:"Maintenance",tags:[{title:"Walls",enabled:true,tags:[{title:"Brickwall"},{title:"Woodenwall"}]},{title:"Roof"}]},{title:"Gardening"}]};

function itemFilter(item) {
  // enabled? done with this item
  if (item.enabled) return item;
  // not enabled and no tags? set to null
  if (!item.tags) return null;
  // filter all children, remove null children
  item.tags = item.tags.map(child => itemFilter(child)).filter(child => child);
  return item;
}

console.log(itemFilter(sourceData));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100vh !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could pass `enabled` parameter down to lower levels of recursion if true value is found on some of the upper levels and based on that add path to the results or not.

```js
const data ={"title":"Work","tags":[{"title":"Cleaning","tags":[{"title":"Floors"},{"title":"Windows","enabled":true},{"title":"Ceilings","enabled":true}]},{"title":"Maintenance","tags":[{"title":"Walls","enabled":true,"tags":[{"title":"Brickwall"},{"title":"Wooden wall"}]},{"title":"Roof"}]},{"title":"Gardening"}]}

function paths(data, prev = '', enabled = false) {
  const result = [];
  prev += (prev ? "." : '') + data.title;
  if (!enabled && data.enabled) enabled = true;

  if (!data.tags) {
    if (enabled) {
      result.push(prev);
    }
  } else {
    data.tags.forEach(el => result.push(...paths(el, prev, enabled)))
  }
  return result;
}

const result = paths(data)
console.log(result)
```